# the program is running on code blocks and after it stops

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10

float func ( int *arr, int n, int *count ) 
{
    int *p,i;        
    float sum=0;
    p=arr;          

    for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
        sum += *p;
        p++;
    }

    sum /= n;          
    count=0;          
    p=arr;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)   //לולאה שעוברת על כל המערך ומוסיפה כל תוכן של איברבמערך שיותר גדול מהממוצע
    {
        *count+= (*p>sum);
        p++;
    }
    return sum;        
}

void main()
{
    int i, count=0, arr[N]={0}, n=N;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
       printf("Please enter your grade\n");
       scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);

    printf("The average in class is: %f and the number of students that had the best grades(MORE) are: %d \n",func(arr,n,count),count);


}
```

I need some help on this program. 
the code is above,
the program need to get from the users 10 grades and then print average and count how many grades is more then the average

Comment: Yes, we don't really make your homework for you here...

Comment: It is just a little problem on the code.

Comment: it stops after getting from user the grades @Jayesh

Comment: Remove the comments in the code,please! It looks untidy with those letters!

Comment: No, write your code and your comments in English.

Comment: @Basile yes,but only if they are not irrelevent though.

Comment: @hila , you mean the execution window closes without printing the last printf?

Comment: yes @CoolGuy exactlly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating sum and count in `func`, so you can't return two values at a time. so count the marks which are greater then average in `main()`.

Try this-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10

float func ( int *arr, int n)
{
        int *p,i;
        float sum=0;
        p=arr;

        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                sum += *p;
                p++;
        }

        sum /= n;
        printf("%lf \n",sum);

        return sum;
}
int countfun(int *arr, float sum)
{
        int i,count = 0;

        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
                if(arr[i] > sum)
                        count++;
        }
        return count;
}

void main()
{
        int i, count=0, arr[N]={0}, n=N;
        float sum=0;

        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
                printf("Please enter your grade\n");
                scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                printf("%d ",arr[i]);

        sum = func(arr,n);
        count = countfun(arr,sum);
        printf("The average in class is: %f and the number of students that had the best grades(MORE) are: %d \n",sum,count);
}
```

Comment: but now I just need to do another func for counting the students that their grades are more then the average. or I can put the pointer of count somehow in the original func? @sathish

Comment: @Hila try the new changes

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` function is incorrectly declared. You should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), which is probably used by your Codeblocks IDE...) then you should **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). And you should test the result of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

BTW,

```
count = 0; // better written as count = NULL;
```

is wrong: it is clearing the pointer. You probably want

```
*count = 0;
```

Also, your last `printf` is supposing some order of evaluation (since you expect the call to `func` to change `count` before printing `count`), so is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need:

```
    float avg = func(arr,n,&count);
    // from http://stackoverflow.com/a/25382154/841108
    printf("The average in class is: %f and the number"
           " of students that had the best grades are: %d \n",
          avg,count);
```

Plese show or tell your teacher that you got help on SO (he will find out anyway)

BTW, I can't understand why students are asking their homework on the web. They don't learn anything by doing that, and their teacher will notice anyway.

Comment: +1 probably `printf` causing  issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `getchar()` just after the last `printf()` to wait for a character.

You think that the execution window closes without printing. That is wrong. It does print and then exits before you can even see the output.

P:S - You have some problems with your code as mentioned in the rest of the answers. Fix them and then try this